# How can I watch a side-by-side 3D video in 2D?

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-conversion, matroska, 3d

I have a 3D movie (`.MKV`), with side-by-side 3D, and it works just fine at home. Now I want to see it at my friend's house, and they don't have a 3D system.

Is there any way to crop one of the sides on VLC or convert it to 2D?

My friend uses a Mac, but I can use Mac OS X or Windows 7 to play the file.

Comment: he has a mac, but he also uses vmware, so mac osx or windows 7. i just want the full size of one of the views, but i don't mind, if i need to convert it or just setting the player

Comment: Ok, I just tested in MPChc and A .MKV video file I was able to "move Left" in View/Pan&Scan and "zoom" Using the EVR renderer . For the Move or the zoom, if it isnt Keyshorts, it would take a lot of menu clicking.  For the Codec, I do have a MKV codec installed, i am not sure if it was needed. VLC has a tendancy to play more formats than MPC without any codec additions to the system.

Comment: VLC doesn't have a 'tendancy' to handle more formats than MPC, it's just that MPC keeps the codecs independant from the player. This is advantageous for a number of reasons. A codec package like CCCP is a much better setup than a single VLC install.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Bino 3d](http://bino3d.org/), a video player for Windows, OS X and Linux, does exactly what you are looking for. Just select 'left/right, half width' from the input menu and 'left' or 'right' from the output menu.

[image: Screenshot]

---

Regarding VLC, you can use new filter named "wall". It not perfect but easier than @Amit's suggestion.

See these links for more information:

- https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/wall
- http://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=14623

Comment: for a video in 1920x804px ratio, additionally you need to go to Preferences->Settings->Video and set "Force source Aspect ration" to "2.39:1"

Comment: On Linux I installed version 1.6.6 with `sudo apt install bino` and it seems to work, but it is **very buggy**: When you try to scip forward, it crashes

Answer (score 45):

I found this forum post on the VideoLAN forums: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=104074

This was the title of the post:

> How to watch 3D SBS in VLC 2.0 and higher
>
> by Tesseract83233 » Mon Sep 10, 2012 12:08 am

The question was:

> I got a 3D side-by-side MKV-Movie but I only have a 2D TV - my question was how to get only the picture of the "left eye" in fullscreen with the right aspect ratio?

This is the solution:

> And after about an hour of playing around... that's how I solved it:
>
> 1. Start VLC (you don't have to play a video at this time)
> 2. Go to "Tools" -> "Preferences" (CTRL+P on Windows)
> 3. On the lower left corner choose "Show settings" -> "All"
> 4. On the left part of the settings window, scroll down and select "Video"
> 5. On the right part of the settings window, scroll down to "Source aspect ratio"
> 6. Type in the aspect ratio with the width doubled - for example 32:9 for a 16:9 video, or 8:3 for a 4:3 video...
> 7. Click "Save" and exit VLC 
>      ---Keep in mind that the changed aspect ratio will be saved for all your videos - remove it after watching 3D or your normal videos might
>      seem to be a bit stretched  ---
> 8. Start VLC and play your 3D video, pause somewhere at the start
> 9. If you don't already know, check your video resolution under "Tools" -> "Media Information" (CTRL+I on Windows) -> "Codec"
> 10. Go to "Tools" -> "Effects and Filters" (CTRL+E on Windows)
> 11. Go to "Video Effects" -> "Crop"
> 12. On "Right" type in the half of your horizontal pixels  for example: 1920x1080 ---> 1920/2 = 960 px or: 1280x720 ---> 1280/2 = 640
>       px
> 13. Click on "Close", hit "Play" and enjoy your movie in 2D ;D
>
> If the video feeds are one on top of the other the same applies except
>   double the height (16:9 > 16:18) and crop the bottom by 1080/2 > 540px
>   or 360px.

Comment: Instead of setting a fixed aspect ratio it is also possible to set a custom list of aspect ratio in the settings, which are then shown in the Video > Aspect Ratio menu

Comment: This kinda works, but then my video has the wrong aspect ratio (original 1920x804px per side)

Answer (score 8):

[Nvidia 3D vision Video Player](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/128699/en-us) will play 3D SBS movies back as a 2D movie. Note that it works only on Windows.

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/object/3d-vision-video-player-1.7.2-driver.html

Answer (score 3):

### Solution for red/green glasses

Tools, Effects and filters, Video effect tab, Use the the scroll bar and go right to advanced, check anaglyph 3d

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b26FIZ2mZXQ

Comment: This only converts the 3d source to anaglyph 3d to watch with red/green glasses.
it would call this a solution.