# How can I watch Half-OU or Half-SBS 3D movies on PC/laptop with SMPlayer?

Tags: video, matroska, 3d

How can I watch Half-OU or Half-SBS 3D movies on PC/laptop with SMPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/) for watching Half-OU or Half-SBS 3D `.mkv` movies in 2D format on your PC/laptop/2D TV.

Go to `MENU` `Video` `3D Stereo Filter`

Choose your input format, then set output format to

> Mono output

Also check this [this](https://superuser.com/questions/389310/how-can-i-watch-a-side-by-side-3d-video-in-2d) thread.